# Docker pull from artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

Docker pull resulting the following error, we are trying to pull the image from artifactory (docker repo)

```
% docker pull artifactory.myorg.com/docker/axyu1325/kargo:0.3.0
```

Error response from daemon:

> Missing or empty Content-Length header

Comment: That seems like an issue you'll have to follow up with your local Artifactory admins; an Internet forum intrinsically won't be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade artifactory to 7.0.0 or later, or downgrade your docker client.